# How instances of Django's generic view classes created?

Tags: python, django, web

I am trying to understand how Django works and here is one question. Say we have this simple CreateView:

```
class ListCreate(CreateView):
    model = ToDoList
    fields = ['title']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ListCreate, self).get_context_data()
        context['title'] = 'Add a new list'
        return context
```

Now, as far as I know, you create an instance of a class by my_instance = MyClass(). Untill then the code that describes the MyClass is just a code. So my question is, at what point in time the instance of ListCreate() is created and what is the name of that instance?

Comment: An instance of the view is created when a request matching a urlpattern for that view comes in, the `as_view` classmethod returns a function that creates the instance and calls its dispatch method, what do you mean by "name of that instance"?

Comment: well, when you do my_instance = MyClass(), 'my_instance' is the name of the instance. Or for example if you have a class Car() then you will do some_car = Car(), so 'some_car' here is the name of the instance of Car() class. When you need, you can access class methods and attributes by some_car.some_method. So now, how do I access the methods of ListCreate() class if I don't know the name of the instance. (Sorry if I am using wrong terminology here)

Comment: You access the view instance via `self` in the view's methods. Instances do not have "names", many variables could reference them or they could be referenced in a list, where or how exactly do you want to reference the view instance?

Comment: I see, thanks. It makes sense. I was trying to reference the view instance in the Django shell just to understand how Django works.

Comment: The `as_view` method that you pass to urlpatterns returns a function that creates the instance and calls it's dispatch method https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/views/generic/base.py#L61. You could emulate this in a shell using `ListCreate.as_view()(request)` or something similar if you are able to mock a request object